# jQuery validate remote not sending correct json data

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

There are a number of similar posts but this is not working for me.  I've tried it about 20 different ways now so if someone can put me on the right track its much appreciated.

First I tried this.  Seems to be correct according to the docs but the JSON that is being sent is just the element id ('element' is a jQuery element ref)

```
if (valData.ValidationItems[i].Date) {
    element.rules("add", {
        remote: {
            url: websiteBase + "Home/DateValidation",
            type: "post",
            data: {
                Date: function () { return $("#" + element[0].id).val() },
                Min: valData.ValidationItems[i].RangeMin,
                Max: valData.ValidationItems[i].RangeMax
            },
            dataType: "json"
        },
        messages: { remote: valData.ValidationItems[i].ValidationMessage }
    });
}
```

This next bit that I tried works one time but then locks up the browser

```
remote: function () {
    var remoteData = {
        Date: $("#" + element[0].id).val(),
        Min: data.ValidationItems[i].RangeMin,
        Max: data.ValidationItems[i].RangeMax
    }
    var remoteJSON = JSON.stringify(remoteData);
    var r = {
        url: websiteBase + "Home/DateValidation",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data: remoteJSON
    }
    return r;
}
```

This is using jQuery validate 1.8 which is the version installed for MVC 3 projects.

Comment: You do **not** need to specify the `data` item for the field itself... that value is already sent by default.

Comment: I'm not, I'm specifying a 'Date' item, and I need to include 3 things in the JSON

Comment: Can you try: `data: remoteData` instead of `data: remoteJSON`?

Comment: Oh yeah I tried that and about 40 other combinations.  See my answer below.  Thx for the idea tho!

Answer (score 0):

So after trying this about 40 different ways I found one that works.  jQuery validate remote really tries to NOT encode your result as JSON if at all possible.  In most cases it encoded the "data" like a query string.

```
remote: {
    url: websiteBase + "Home/DateValidation",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        Date: $("#" + element[0].id).val(),
        Min: valData.ValidationItems[i].RangeMin,
        Max: valData.ValidationItems[i].RangeMax
    })
}
```

Comment: To make this work with as MVC controller using JsonResult I had to add
contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8"

Comment: In any case I still can't get it to return the UPDATED date value from the input element

Answer (score 0):

OK got this working.  The key is do NOT try to send valid JSON data to the server using the remote function.  Don't specify the contentType or dataType.  Make sure your controller or web service is prepared to receive a form POST.  Also the documentation is incorrect in that it says if you specify the "data" property it will override the default.  That is not true.  Finally, none of the methods from the Documentation or other posts about retrieving the element's value in the remote function work.  The only way to get it to fire the event and retrieve the updated element value every time it is updated is by using the "remote" method's default functionality.  In my case the element ID is a variable so this was undesirable.

In the end this is what worked for me, sending 3 values to the server encoded as form post parameters.

```
remote: {
    url: websiteBase + "Home/DateValidation",
    type: "post",
    cache: false,
    data: {
        Min: valData.ValidationItems[i].RangeMin,
        Max: valData.ValidationItems[i].RangeMax
    }
}
```

In the controller I retrieve the value and the dynamic element ID using

```
public ActionResult DateValidation(FormCollection parameters) { 
    bool valid = true;
    try {
        string date = parameters[0];
        string elementID = parameters.Keys[0].ToString();
   ...
```